# Using excel formula to copy a column between workbooks if first cell contains any info

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I'm tyring to look for a way to return a range of cells with just the lookup function. Is this really possible?

Basically like this:
=LOOKUP([MasterBook.xlsm]Sheet3!$A:$A,?)

I just want the function to look in the main workbook through all of Column A and return all cells for Column A that have something in them.

**EDIT** for poster below:
Sure. I have two workbooks; one workbook is essentially a local product that has a "master" sheet on top and then individual worksheets following it that have all of their information extracted from the master sheet.  The second workbook is a local copy of a product that I send to a non-local entity higher up the food chain. Basically I need to pull information from the individual sheets in my first workbook and put it in the appropriate columns in the second workbook. I have a macro that gets the info from my sheets in the one workbook over to the other, but the second workbook is formatted differently. I was looking for a way to use a formula if possible.

The macro I am referring to is:

```
Sub CopyTest()
    Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

    Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Local Workbook.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet3").Columns("A")
    Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Nonlocal Workbook.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A")

    sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
End Sub
```

All this does is pull the specified column from one sheet and put it in the column on the second book; but it just pastes it starting in the first block.  Since the non-local book is formatted differently, the column I need to transfer to doesn't start until Row 9. *shrug* I have ideas abuot what I'm trying to do with this, but my ideas tend to exceed my technical ability (which occasionally makes it difficult to explain). :)

Comment: Basically, you cannot return a `Range` with a formula (actually, some like `OFFSET` may but are uneasy to use except in a named range). Would you tell us more so we could help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how *different* your workbooks are formatted. Here is two way to handle this:

**Adapt your macro**

Instead of copying the whole column, you can copy paste, only the values you want to.
Here is an example:

```
Sub CopyTest()
    Dim rSource As Range, rTarget As Range
    Dim lEnd As Long

    lEnd = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rSource = Workbooks("Local Workbook.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:A" & lEnd)
    Set rTarget = Workbooks("Nonlocal Workbook.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A9")

    rSource.Copy Destination:=rTarget
End Sub
```

**Use a formula**

If your data are **not in the same order**, you'd better use a `VLOOKUP` formula.

See [how it works](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php).

Don't hesitate to post another question with what you've built for some help. Please give as much details as possible so we could help you the best way.

**[EDIT] Another try following the comments**

```
Option Explicit
Dim wTarget As Workbook

Sub mainCopy()
    Dim bGo As Boolean
    bGo = True
    'Add a new workbook to copy the data - do you want the user to select one?
    Set wTarget = Application.Workbooks.Add()
    Do While bGo
        CopyTest
        bGo = MsgBox("Do you want to import data from another workbook?", vbYesNo, "Continue?")
    Loop
End Sub

Sub CopyTest()
    Dim rSource As Range, rTarget As Range
    Dim lEnd As Long, lCol As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vFile As Variant

    vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xls", _
        1, "Select One File To Open", , False)
    'if the user didn't select a file, exit sub
    If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
    Workbooks.Open vFile

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        'do you need to copy the columns separately?
'        For lCol = 1 To 10
            'find the last cell of the 10th column
            lEnd = ws.Cells(65536, 10).End(xlUp).Row

            Set rSource = ws.Range("A1:J" & lEnd)
            'How can we define the target worksheet?
            Set rTarget = wTarget.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A9")
            rSource.Copy Destination:=rTarget
'        Next lCol
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: I am trying the vlookup but I just don't have much luck with it with this much stuff spread out everywhere. The macro above, again, does some of what works and some that doesn't. Basically I have two issues with it:  First, my non-local book has sum cells at the bottom of its' sheets that are deleted out when I paste the information into the destination columns.  Obviously I would liek to keep those things there instead of having to rewrite all the forumlas from the import.  Second issue to follow...

Comment: @Jon: for your sum issue, you can either add the formula with vba at the bottom of the new pasted data (best solution) or insert rows to move down your formulas (probably more tricky because there will remain empty rows). Waiting for the second issue :)

Comment: The second issue is really a refinement.  I would like to loop different versions of this macro so that I can pull everything I need from one sheet to the appropriate destination sheet.  Basically I need to pull about 10 columns of info from each(of over 30) source worksheet in the first book to the respective sheet in the destination.  Since it's nearly 30 sheets per book to update i would like to be able to update each worksheet with only one macro. The way they've always done things is either manually entering it all or for the "technologically savvy" fogies copy/paste the information.

Comment: @Jon: do you select or create the target workbook? how can you find the target worksheets, do you want the user to select it? do the 10 columns go on the same worksheet?

Comment: @Jon: i've edited my answer to show what the code could look like - there are still some holes you could try to patch by yourself :) (a good way to learn) depending on the way you want to handle this

Comment: I have both workbooks in my directory already created; basically no one else will mess with the books.  Each worksheet within the two workbooks is named for a department within the company - the only thing different namewise is the workbook itself.  i did the individual sheets in the first workbook because it's horribly inefficient for me to try to scan and pull out each department line by line.

Comment: Ideally, I'm the only user for these. The first workbook is basically my own copy of everything; I use it to separate out all department and company info that we track.  No one uses this workbook.  The second book(the non-local) has the info that higher ups within the company use for their "snapshots." When they decide they don't want something there or want something added then I just change what's in it.  Before I got here they just created the second workbook manually and sent it off each time; now I keep a local copy so it doesn't have to be recreated every time.

Comment: @Jon: then, you'd probably better try something with the inputs I gave you and come with a new question when you don't understand something or need some improvement. And don't forget to give the explanation you gave me so we can fully understand what you intend to do